# Create ID for each string attribute in QGIS

Tags: qgis, gdal, rasterization

I'm trying to rasterize a vector layer by using an attribute filed stored as string, I got the confirmation through the GDAL mailinglist serv that gdal_rasterize does not work with string field. So my question is: is there an easy way to create an ID column based on a existing string column? Basically that would something like this:

```
"Forest and Woodland" ----- 1
"Shrubland and Grassland"---2
...
```

and so on

I only have 7 district strings so I suppose I could write some basic python if loop on the field calculator but what if this value was greater?

I'm using QGIS 2.8 and latest GDAL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the string field is named `text` and the field with corresponding integer values is named `code` and field `code` already exists, then the following Python code will do the job.

```
# get active layer
aLayer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()

# get fieldindex
fni_t = aLayer.fieldNameIndex('text')
fni_c = aLayer.fieldNameIndex('code')

# initializations
value_dict = {}
count = 1
aLayer.startEditing()

# iterate over features; if text is already a key in the dict, then assign its associated
# value to the coding field, otherwise insert a new key into dict and increment the value
for feat in aLayer.getFeatures():
    if feat[fni_t] in value_dict:
        feat[fni_c] = value_dict[feat[fni_t]]
    else:
        feat[fni_c] = count
        value_dict[feat[fni_t]] = count
        count += 1
    aLayer.updateFeature(feat)

# save changes and stop editing
aLayer.commitChanges()
```

Comment: Thanks for the full script, but when I run it I get the following error `if feat.attribute(fn) in value_dict:
NameError: name 'fn' is not defined`

Comment: Sorry for that mistake, I pasted the wrong line of code. I have edited the answer.